# How to combine DataTables with other matchers?

Tags: scala, specs2

I was trying to populate a container using specs2 DataTable and then check some conditions on it. The problem is that matchers after DataTable are ignored. Consider the code below

```
class MySpec extends Specification with DataTables {

"A Container" should {
"after data is added container should have the following data" in new TestContainer {
  "a"  | "flag" | "d"   |
  100  ! 1      ! "abc" |
  300  ! 1      ! "abc" |
  200  ! 0      ! "xyz" |>
  { (a, flag, d) =>
    container.add(Data(a, flag, d)) must not(throwA[Exception])
  } 
  container.size must_== 3 // Ignored
  1 must_== 2 // Ignored
  }
}
}
```

Please let me know what am I missing and how to make lines marked as `// Ignored` to be validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is a bug. It is fixed in the latest 2.4-SNAPSHOT.